# Sphinx autosummary produces two summaries for each class

Tags: python, python-sphinx, numpydoc

I'm using Sphinx+autodoc+autosummary to generate documentation for my project (`mrpy`).

I am doing a two-layer summary, where in the `index.rst` I have (minimally)

```
mrpy
====

.. autosummary::
   :toctree: _autosummary
   :template: modules.rst

   mrpy.stats
   <other modules...>
```

I use a custom template for the module-level autosummary as you can see. I do this so that on the module-level summary, I also get a summary of the objects within the module, which each link to their own pages. For reference, my `modules.rst` file is

```
{{ fullname }}
{{ underline }}

.. automodule:: {{ fullname }}

   {% block functions %}
   {% if functions %}
   .. rubric:: Functions

   .. autosummary::
      :toctree: {{ objname }}
   {% for item in functions %}
      {{ item }}
   {%- endfor %}
   {% endif %}
   {% endblock %}

   {% block classes %}
   {% if classes %}
   .. rubric:: Classes

   .. autosummary::
      :toctree: {{ objname }}
      :template: class.rst
   {% for item in classes %}
      {{ item }}
   {%- endfor %}
   {% endif %}
   {% endblock %}

   {% block exceptions %}
   {% if exceptions %}
   .. rubric:: Exceptions

   .. autosummary::
   {% for item in exceptions %}
      {{ item }}
   {%- endfor %}
   {% endif %}
   {% endblock %}
```

`mrpy.stats` contains just three classes, which get summarised beautifully when following the link in the table produced on the index page. When following the link to one of those classes, I use another custom template, `class.rst`:

```
{{ fullname }}
{{ underline }}

.. currentmodule:: {{ module }}

.. autoclass:: {{ objname }}

   {% block methods %}

   {% if methods %}
   .. rubric:: Methods

   .. autosummary::
      :toctree: {{ objname }}
   {% for item in methods %}
      ~{{ name }}.{{ item }}
   {%- endfor %}
   {% endif %}
   {% endblock %}

   {% block attributes %}
   {% if attributes %}
   .. rubric:: Attributes

   .. autosummary::
      :toctree: {{ objname }}
   {% for item in attributes %}
      ~{{ name }}.{{ item }}
   {%- endfor %}
   {% endif %}
   {% endblock %}
```

However, the page for this class contains the title, as expected, the class docstring, as expected, but **two** tabulated summaries of the methods and attributes of the class.

Anyone know how to get rid of one of the redundant tables?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that the answer is that numpydoc screws around with autosummary. Adding `numpydoc_show_class_members=False` to the conf.py fixes the problem. Solution found here: https://github.com/phn/pytpm/issues/3#issuecomment-12133978